# How to achieve topic authentication after ssl client authentication with rabbitmq in conjunction with mqtt and a backend for authentification?

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, mqtt, ssl-client-authentication

I set up RabbitMq v3.6.6 and I'm trying to achieve topic authentication after a successful client ssl authentication. The Client connecting is using mqtt.

## The configuration so far

```
#/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
[
  {rabbit, [
    {ssl_cert_login_from, common_name},
    {auth_mechanisms, ['EXTERNAL']},
    {tcp_listeners, [{"127.0.0.1", 5672}]},
    {ssl_listeners, [{"0.0.0.0", 5671}]},
    {ssl_options, [
      {cacertfile,          "/path_to/CA.crt"},
      {certfile,            "/path_to/certfile.crt"},
      {keyfile,             "/path_to/keyfile.key"},
      {verify, verify_peer},
      {fail_if_no_peer_cert, true}
      ]},
    {auth_backends, [rabbit_auth_backend_http]},
    {rabbitmq_auth_backend_http, [
      {http_method,          post },
      {user_path,            "https://127.0.0.1/auth/user"},
      {vhost_path,             "https://127.0.0.1/auth/vhost"},
      {resource_path, "https://127.0.0.1/auth/resource"},
      {topic_path, "https://127.0.0.1/auth/topic"}
      ]}
  ]},
  {rabbitmq_mqtt, [
                  {default_user,     <<"user">>},
                  {default_pass,     <<"pass">>},
                  {allow_anonymous,  true},
                  {vhost,            <<"/">>},
                  {exchange,         <<"amq.topic">>},
                  {subscription_ttl, 86400000},
                  {tcp_listeners,    [{"127.0.0.1", 1883}]},
                  {ssl_listeners,    [8883]},
                  {ssl_cert_login, true}
  ]}
].
```

I have installed the plugins `rabbitmq_auth_backend_http` (https://bintray.com/rabbitmq/community-plugins/download_file?file_path=rabbitmq_auth_backend_http-3.6.x-1b27d722.ez) and `rabbitmq_topic_authorization`(https://github.com/airboxlab/rabbitmq-topic-authorization/releases/download/v3.6.6/rabbitmq_topic_authorization.ez) and enabled them.

```
$ sudo rabbitmq-plugins list -e
[e*] amqp_client                  3.6.6
[e*] mochiweb                     2.13.1
[E*] rabbitmq_auth_backend_http   
[E*] rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl  3.6.6
[E*] rabbitmq_management          3.6.6
[e*] rabbitmq_management_agent    3.6.6
[E*] rabbitmq_mqtt                3.6.6
[E*] rabbitmq_topic_authorization 
[e*] rabbitmq_web_dispatch        3.6.6
[e*] webmachine                   1.10.3
```

## Why I configured like this

At https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-mechanism-ssl there is a note:

> Note that the authenticated user will then be looked up in the configured authentication / authorisation backend(s) - this will be the mnesia-based user database by default, but could include other backends if so configured.

I did this by including and enabling plugins and configured `auth_mechanisms` to `EXTERNAL`. And `auth_backends` to `rabbit_auth_backend_http`

In the mqtt pluging documentation (https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html) there is a section **Authentication with SSL client certificates**, which is i want to achieve. I styled the important part in **bold**:

> Authentication with SSL client certificates
>   The MQTT adapter can authenticate SSL-based connections by extracting a name from the client's SSL certificate, without using a password.
>
> For safety the server must be configured with the SSL options fail_if_no_peer_cert set to true and **verify set to verify_peer**, to force all SSL clients to have a verifiable client certificate.
>
> To switch this feature on, **set ssl_cert_login to true** for the rabbitmq_mqtt application. For example:
>     `[
>         {rabbitmq_mqtt, [{ssl_cert_login, true}]}
>       ].`
>
> To use the Common Name instead, add:
>   `{rabbit, [{ssl_cert_login_from, common_name}]}`
>   to your configuration.
>
> Note that:
>   The authenticated user must exist in the **configured authentication / authorisation backend(s).**
>   Clients **must not supply username and password.**

## The Problem

When I want to subscribe via `sudo mosquitto_sub -h my-backend --cafile ca.crt --key client_keyfile.key --cert client_certfile.crt -t '#' -p 8883` 
I get the Error `Connection Refused: bad user name or password.`

The RabbitMq logs show the following output:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 6-Mar-2017::15:01:51 ===
MQTT login failed for "my-hostname" auth_failure: Refused
```

At this point I expected RabbitMq to ask the backend for authentication instead of refusing right away. But there is no request at all to my backend-server. Furthermore, there shouldn't be an error complaining about name or password as im using client certifcates.
I tested the backend-server with curl and i get `allow` response as expected. I could also verify the access in the nginx logs. So i guess the `rabbitmq_auth_backend_http` does not work properly or something else is misconfigured.

Has anyone an idea why the backend-server is not requested?

Answer (score 0):

`=ERROR REPORT==== 6-Mar-2017::15:01:51 ===
MQTT login failed for "my-hostname" auth_failure: Refused`

For above problem, you need to add user 'my-hostname' first:
`sudo rabbitmqctl add_user my-hostname my-hostname`

Then set permission:
`sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / my-hostname ".*" ".*" ".*"`

OR, you can add user through rabbitmq management GUI.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation here : https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#topic-authorisation the auth mechanism 'EXTERNAL' is not available.

The following aliases are available:

> internal, ldap, http, amqp, dummy

However

> External

is allowed in a plugin that you must include if you use it.